# Python: Bloomberg Open API cannot establish socket under OSX

Tags: python, macos, sockets, bloomberg

I have a stange problem: After installing the Bloomberg Open API c++ libs and the Python bindings appropriately, I still cannot run their examples. In particular, when I try to run the SimpleFieldInfoExample.py I get the error:

```
ERROR blpapi_platformtransporttcp.cpp:671 blpapi.session.transporttcp.{1}.<localhost:8194> Connection failed
```

I already checked that the port is not bussy by another program. Could it be that it is a permission issue? or another issue in how OSX handels socket connections?

I deeply appreciate any help

Andy

Comment: Do you have a Bloomberg terminal running (and logged in) on the machine?

Comment: Hi, I am using the Open API (http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/) which as far as I understand does not need to have a terminal running in the background, right?

Comment: No it needs a terminal running. Only the API is open, the data is not: no terminal, no data!

Comment: Ok, thanks. Where can I download that terminal app, is it free, or does it involve a paid subscription?

Comment: It's approximately $1,500 per month.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a little bit too expensive for my portfolio script ;)